# Pyside or PyQt support Qt 5.0 and Qt Quick 2

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside

Did Qt 5 and Qt Quick supported by last Version Pyside or PyQt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of PyQt (4.10?) works with Qt5. It does *not* support Qt Quick 2, AFAIK. I don't believe PySide supports either.

Comment: PySide seems to support QT Quick Collibri according to their wiki: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Utilizing-Qt-Quick-Colibri-in-PySide